# Solutions to increase roof insulation with raised tie trusses

Tags: insulation, roof, truss

My house has raised tie trusses:

[image: Raised tie trusses]

This means that on the second floor the central part of the ceiling is flat, but near the long walls it is slanted. The trusses are 2x6 timber construction, meaning that there is minimal space for insulation in these areas (red squares in the image).

In the space outlined in blue there is more space for insulation, but this area needs to be vented to prevent the roof from overheating and damaging the asphalt shingles.

We are planning to replace the roof with metal in the next year or two. While making this change, I would like to increase the roof insulation. Short of replacing the trusses, what are my options for improving insulation with this roof construction type?

These are the ideas we have considered:

1. Open the ceiling from the inside and replace the blown-in cellulose insulation with closed cell spray foam.
2. Add a layer of rigid foam above the sheathing and below the new roof. This may cause problems with roof venting.
3. Remove the exterior sheathing and sister in 2x6s or even 2x8s to create additional space for insulation.

Below is a picture of the roof from the outside showing the small vent.

[image: Picture of roof]

Comment: So on those red bits, put 8" of insulation so there is 2" covering the 2x6 on the inside.

Comment: @SolarMike I've heard of overcladding exteriors with foam insulation, but can you do that on interior ceilings? Installing and finishing drywall over 2" of foam sounds... challenging.

Comment: How is your roof vented?  I see tiny vents at the top of the gable ends, but they look too small to provide adequate air flow.  Are there any vents in the soffits?

Comment: Well, we did it over 2" of sheep’s wool… much more difficult to handle.

Comment: What type of insulation is in the red area now?  If there's nothing there, then even 3-1/2 inches of Rockwool (easy to handle) will reduce the heat loss through that section by around 95%.

Comment: @SteveSh there are no vents in the soffits, an issue which we'll address when we do the new roof. There is blown in cellulose for insulation currently.